# Validating Docbook 5.0, link/linkend

Tags: docbook, docbook-5

I am wondering why this Docbook 5.0 document is not valid:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<article xmlns='http://docbook.org/ns/docbook' xmlns:xlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink' version='5.0'>
<section xml:id='H_0'>
<title>This is a title</title>
<para>
Blah <link linkend='H_0'>This is a link</link>blah blah blah.</para>
</section>
</article>
```

Here is what I get from `xmlstarlet`:

```
$ xmlstarlet val --err --xsd /usr/share/xml/docbook/schema/xsd/5.0/docbook.xsd test.xml
test.xml:3.22: Element '{http://docbook.org/ns/docbook}section', attribute '{http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace}id': '' is not a valid value of the atomic type 'xs:ID'.
test.xml:6.25: Element '{http://docbook.org/ns/docbook}link', attribute 'linkend': '' is not a valid value of the atomic type 'xs:IDREF'.
test.xml - invalid
```

I just want internal links in the document, to the sections.

Addition: maybe this is an xmlstarlet problem, as other tools happily process the files. Anyway, I'd be glad if somebody could explain the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it’s a bug in the version of `xmlstarlet` you have installed? It works for me on Debian:

```
$ xmlstarlet val --err --xsd /usr/share/xml/docbook/schema/xsd/5.0/docbook.xsd -
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<article xmlns='http://docbook.org/ns/docbook'
         xmlns:xlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink' version='5.0'>
<section xml:id='H_0'>
<title>This is a title</title>
<para>
Blah <link linkend='H_0'>This is a link</link>blah blah blah.</para>
</section>
</article>
- - valid
    ^^^^^
```

Here’s my `xmlstarlet` version info:

```
$ xmlstarlet --version
1.6.1
compiled against libxml2 2.9.4, linked with 20904
compiled against libxslt 1.1.29, linked with 10129
```

---

Incidentally, though, the DocBook document in the question isn’t actually valid—because a DocBook `article` element must have either a `title` or `info` child:

```
$ cat > test.xml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<article xmlns='http://docbook.org/ns/docbook'
         xmlns:xlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink' version='5.0'>
<section xml:id='H_0'>
<title>This is a title</title>
<para>
Blah <link linkend='H_0'>This is a link</link>blah blah blah.</para>
</section>
</article>

$ java -jar /usr/share/java/jing.jar \
    /usr/share/xml/docbook/schema/rng/5.0/docbook.rng test.xml
test.xml:3:23: error: element "section" not allowed yet; expected element "info",
"subtitle", "title" or "titleabbrev"
```

See http://tdg.docbook.org/tdg/5.0/article.html:

> article — An article.
>
> **Synopsis**
>
> Sequence of:
>
> - One of:
>
>   - Sequence of:
>
>     - Interleave of:
>
>       - `title`
>       - `titleabbrev?`
>       - `subtitle?`
>     - `info?` (db.titleforbidden.info)
>   - `info` (db.titlereq.info)

The lack of a `?` question mark after `title` and `info` there, combined with the `One of` means that one or the other of `title` or `info` is required.

I’m surprised the XSD schema doesn’t catch that. But I guess maybe it’s an indication that to make sure your DocBook documents actually are valid, you probably want to consider validating against the RelaxNG schema (`/usr/share/xml/docbook/schema/rng/5.0/docbook.rng` file) instead.

Comment: Thanks a lot. `xmlstarlet --version' actually prints an empty line, but it's libxml 2.9.2 and libxslt 1.1.28 Am using Ubuntu.

Comment: Strange. Could instead be a bug in that libxml2 version I guess

Comment: Also, `info' is not mentioned in Docbook definitive guide?

Comment: The `info` element page is at http://tdg.docbook.org/tdg/5.0/titlereq.info.html, if that’s what you mean?

Comment: Ah, yes, I was looking at v. 4.5

Comment: Oh, yeah, 4.5 is pretty old now. I think maybe the `info` element was added in 5.0